# WordPress doctype error

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-declaration

How can I add the following code into a WordPress site without the code causing a PHP error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Comment: Not related to the question but FYI, that's not a doctype, it's an XML processing instruction.

Comment: Why do you want to add it to a WordPress site?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to include it in the last line of your php file as

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
```

There's also probably a better way that someone will point out.

Comment: Why the last and not the first line? Shouldn't the xml declaration be at the top?

Comment: If the php doesn't output anything it won't make a difference. If it does however, it should be the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can (depending on the server setup) try disabling PHP short tags. You can either do this in your .htaccess file by inserting this line:

`php_value short_open_tag 0`

Or by using the PHP ini_set function

`ini_set ('short_open_tag', 0);`